# CSS: how to detect position of notch?

Tags: css, ios12

My design needs to be 100vw wide. The layout should cover the whole screen, so I'm using `viewport-fit=cover`. This can cause one element to be covered by the iPhone Xn's notch in landscape orientation. I thought this should fix that:

```
transform: translateX(calc(-1*env(safe-area-inset-right)));
```

It does indeed move the element from underneath the notch, but it turns out that `safe-area-inset-right` = `safe-area-inset-left`; the transformation is applied regardless of whether the notch is on the left or right hand side. [This image](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*ErYVmx3tSWUIgeYrgi17kA.png) from [this post](https://medium.com/@onotakehiko/iphone-x-%E3%81%AE-safari-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-web-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%84%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA-58da5f503d0b) confirms that. Is there a way to only apply the transformation rule if the notch is on the right hand side?

Comment: Not sure if that’s possible using CSS alone. Via JS, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation would allow you to detect whether the screen was “upside down”, but that has no iOS support as of now it seems.